# PHP/mySQL query multiple sql tables into 1 html table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a scheduling application where I need to build a html table report.  I need to get data from my `users`, `attandance`, `week`, and `shift` tables. I also have an array that tells me how many attendance codes they have and what the descriptions are.

For the sake of the demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f8a6f

```
table users:                     table attendance:
userid | name                    userid | code
test   | Test user               test   | 2

table week:                      table shift
week | status                    userid | week | shift | status
1207 | 1                         test   | 1207 | tue   | 1
1214 | 1                         test   | 1207 | wed   | 1
1221 | 0
```

I need to get:

- userid : `users.userid`
- name : `users.name`
- in a loop of the attendance array

  - sum of attendance codes : sum of `attendance.code where attendance.userid=users.userid AND code=1`, sum of attendance.code 2, etc
- in a loop of `week where status != 0`

  - count of shifts worked : count `shift where shift.userid = users.userid AND shift.week = week.week AND status != 0`

So I get something like this:

```
User ID | Name      | Attendance   | Att2      | Week of | Week of
        |           | code 1 (late)|(unexcused)| 12/07   | 12/14
test    | Test user | 0            | 1         | 2       | 3
```

I currently have a ton of loops.
I get the users table into an array, then loop that array for each user, then loop my attendance array querying the attendance table. then loop the users array again querying the shifts table for each week. I was looking to see if there's a way to do it in SQL.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried? Maybe you could setup a SQL fiddle.

Comment: I currently have a ton of loops.  I get the users table into an array, then loop that array for each user, then loop my attendance array querying the attendance table.  then loop the users array again querying the shifts table for each week.  I was looking to see if there's a way to do it in SQL.

Comment: Setting up a SQL fiddle will allow folks to attempt solutions that will "stand-alone" in SQL.

Comment: @vp_arth I'm doing a JOIN in printing the schedule out (getting user.name where user.userid=shift.userid) but I don't understand how to put the weeks table in the mix

Comment: want you to get different columns number here? column per each `status=1` week?

Comment: make two separate queries, mixing both into one will make it too hard :)